# Is there a name for the space of vectors orthogonal to a given vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a vector $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ orthogonal to $\mathbf{v}$, namely $$\{\mathbf{u} \in \mathbb{R}^n: \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}=0\},$$ forms a subspace.  In fact, it is the null space of the $1 \times n$ matrix
$$\left(
\begin{matrix}
v_1 & v_2 & \cdots & v_n \\
\end{matrix}
\right)$$
if $\mathbf{v}=(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n)$.

*Question*:  Is there a specific name or notation for this vector space?

Comment: It is called a hyperplane.

Comment: The notation is $\langle \mathbf{v}\rangle^\perp$ and if $F$ is a subspace or even a set then it's *orthogonal* is denoted by $F^\perp$.

Comment: @user69810 The tangent space of a point at the hyperplane, and the plane is defined by using $\mathbf{v}$ as normal, to be precise.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao Don't you need to start with some kind of surface to get a tangent space? In this case we are given the vector but we are not told that it is the normal to a surface.

Comment: @user69810: The set $\{(1,y):y\in\mathbb R\}$ is a hyperplane in $\mathbb R^2$ but is not the space of vectors orthogonal to any vector.

Comment: It's not a vector space, since it doesn't have the zero vector.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane) distinguishes these into "vector hyperplane" (those that are vector spaces) and "affine hyperplane" (translations of vector hyperplanes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We usually denote it "W perp", a W with an upside down T as a superscript.  We call it the orthogonal complement.

$$W^\perp$$

Comment: Here $W$ is the line spanned by $v$. It's the ortogonal *complement* in the sense that $\Bbb R^n=W\oplus W^\perp$.

Comment: Although W need not be a line.  It is more general.  W perp is the set of all vectors orthogonal to the subspace W.

Comment: Certainly. Yet the OP was asking for the orthogonal of a vector.

Comment: But the perpendicular applies to any subset of a vector space--it is always a subspace since $S^\perp=\text{span}(S)^\perp$.